# Service gets stops after closing an Activity in which it is created?

Tags: android, android-service

I have created a `Service` and started using an `Activity` on `Button` click, but the `Service` gets stops after I closes an `Activity`. So what should I do to keep running the `Service` without gets stopped?

MainActivity.java

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
  }

public void startService(View v){
    Intent i = new Intent(this, NotStickyService.class);
    startService(i);
}


 public void stopService(View v){
    Intent i = new Intent(this, NotStickyService.class);
    stopService(i);
}
```

Service.java

```
public class NotStickyService extends Service{

    MediaPlayer mp;


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        showToast("onCreate");
        super.onCreate(); 

    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        showToast("onStart");
        mp = new MediaPlayer();     
    AssetFileDescriptor descriptor;
    descriptor = getAssets().openFd("msg.mp3");
        mp.setDataSource(descriptor.getFileDescriptor(),     
        descriptor.getStartOffset(),descriptor.getLength());                                                   
            descriptor.close();
            mp.prepare();
            mp.start();
        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();    
        showToast("onDestroy");        
    }

    private void showToast(String message){
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain your problem deeply? is there only one activity and which is closing after starting the service?

Comment: I am starting service using activity, but when I closes the activity, the service also gets stops. And I am returning START_STICKY from "onStartCommand()".

Comment: Make sure you're starting the service and not just binding it.  Bound services exit when no more activities are bound to them.

Comment: post your code so that we can help